# Turn string into object

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay so I know

```
var str = {}; string.split(' ').forEach(function(val, idx) {str[++idx] = val;});
```

but if string was " Hello world 'how r u' " it would return

```
["1":"Hello","2":"world","3":"how","4":"r","5":"u"]
```

I want it to return

```
["1":"Hello","2":"world","3":"how r u"]
```

so things between ' ' and " " are 1 item how do I make it do that?
btw I'm using node.js

Comment: The second return should be ["1":"Hello","2":"world","3":"'how","4":"r","5":"u'"], you can just split by spaces, and in the processing method, ignore the splits beginning with (at character #1) ', until you find the closing ', this should work for simple ones but not with nested 's

Comment: Is your desired result actually an Javascript object like this: `{"1":"Hello","2":"world","3":"how r u"}` or do you want the result to be an Array?

Comment: Either, as long as I can access each world or string of words individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you louis on swiftirc#javascript for this

```
var out = {}; 'this is "a test" with a "random string of words" 34iuv     38vy 3b8u nuhvbe7yvb 73rvy dsuh bue "f34fdvedfg wr edf Fw efwef" efg3f'.match(/\w+|"(.[^"]+)"/g).forEach(function (str, idx) { out[++idx] = str.replace(/^"|"$/g,''); });
console.log(out);

>> {"1":"this","2":"is","3":"a test","4":"with","5":"a","6":"random string of words","7":"34iuv","8":"38vy","9":"3b8u","10":"nuhvbe7yvb","11":"73rvy","12":"dsuh","13":"bue","14":"f34fdvedfg wr edf Fw efwef","15":"efg3f"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a node.js guru, so I don't know if there is a nice solution by means of regular expressions in the split function, but a solution might be to write a function to first split up the original string into bigger chunk, based on the " or ' character. This will result in an array of strings, which you can then further split up into smaller chunks.